# Sitecore 7.2 Social Connected Module 2.1 authResult=error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-social-connected

I have installed social connected module 2.1 on Sitecore 7.2, then I configured the profile mapping, facebook app, everything was going well.

When I try to login using the "Login with facebook" rendering, I'm getting redirect to the same page with an error query string:

http://sc72rev151021.com/registration?authResult=error_9ffsede-dsdf6-4f50-9b6a-asdasdasd

I checked the log file and I see this error:

> 28144 10:24:36 ERROR The error in ConnectManager occured Exception:
>   Sitecore.Social.Infrastructure.Exceptions.SocialException Message: The
>   given key was not present in the dictionary.
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException Message:
>   The given key was not present in the dictionary. Source: mscorlib
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)    at
>   Sitecore.Social.Facebook.Networks.Providers.FacebookProvider.GetAccountBasicData(Account
>   account)    at
>   Sitecore.Social.Client.Api.ConnectorClientManager.Connect(Account
>   account, Boolean attachAccountToLoggedInUser, Boolean
>   isAsyncProfileUpdate)    at
>   Sitecore.Social.Client.Api.Connector.ConnectorAuthCompleted.AuthCompleted(AuthCompletedArgs
>   args)

Then I recompiled the DLLs, and the code is crashing here (the following code snippet from **Sitecore.Social.Facebook.dll** ):

```
  public AccountBasicData GetAccountBasicData(Account account)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(account, "Account parameter is null");
        IDictionary<string, object> accountData = this.GetAccountData(account, "/me");
        if (accountData == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        string str = string.Concat(accountData["first_name"], " ", accountData["last_name"]);
        AccountBasicData accountBasicDatum = new AccountBasicData()
        {
            Account = account,
            Id = accountData["id"] as string,
            Email = accountData["email"] as string,
            FullName = str
        };
        return accountBasicDatum;
    }

   private IDictionary<string, object> GetAccountData(Account account, string access)
    {
        return this.FacebookRequest(account, access, null, (FacebookClient facebookClient, string feedPath, object inputParams) => facebookClient.Get(feedPath) as IDictionary<string, object>);
    }
```

Any Idea ? Is this module depends on deprecated facebook keys ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide URL of Facebook page on which you are redirected just after trying to login? I guess that it transfers outdated scope of permissions.

Comment: Thank you Anton for the help, first thing the user is on this page http://sc72rev151021.com/registration then he trying to login using facebook rendering, then he will redirected to the same page http://sc72rev151021.com/registration?authResult=error_9ffsede-dsdf6-4f50-9b6a-asdasdasd

Comment: there should be one intermediate request to Facebook between two pages that you mentioned. Use Fiddler or network panel of developer tools in your browser to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this issue is the following:

1. Use any .net reflector, open Sitecore.Socail.Facebook.Dll, create a project from the source code.
2. Fix the errors in the project by adding the required references.
3. Go to this function GetAccountBasicData in FacebookProvider.cs
4. Remove the code inside the function, and add the following code instead.

   string item;
           Assert.IsNotNull(account, "Account parameter is null");

   ```
       IDictionary<string, object> accountData = this.GetAccountData(account, "/me");
       if (accountData == null)
       {
           return null;
       }
       string str = string.Concat(accountData["name"]);
       AccountBasicData accountBasicDatum = new AccountBasicData()
       {
           Account = account,
           Id = accountData["id"] as string
       };
       AccountBasicData accountBasicDatum1 = accountBasicDatum;
       if (accountData.ContainsKey("email"))
       {
           item = accountData["email"] as string;
       }
       else
       {
           item = null;
       }
       accountBasicDatum1.Email = item;
       accountBasicDatum.FullName = str;
       return accountBasicDatum;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Facebook API that is used in Sitecore Social Connected is outdated. Facebook [scope permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions) list was changed. I faced with [similar issue](http://sitecorevn.blogspot.com/2016/04/sitecore-social-connected-21-second-life.html) while adding Facebook application. I think that "Login with facebook" rendering also sends request to Facebook with outdated list of user permissions.

Comment: I did reverse engineering. I got IL code (using ILDASM), updated permissions to new ones. Make from IL code(using ILASM) new dll and it works for me.

Comment: That's what i'm thinking of, I will check your post. thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue with the module and it was caused by outdated SSL version used for social API requests. Sitecore support provided a fix which solved this.